# Aws RDS SQL Server: table's identity auto increasing to a different huge number

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have SQL Server Web Edition 12.00.5000.0.v1 AWS RDS engine.

I am seeing an issue with one of my tables. I have set the table's identity to 1 but it is increasing to a huge number like 10009,89568474589.. etc. Then I need to manually reseed the value to 1 again to make the things working again.

RDS does have limited permissions to the server so I can't check the logs. Also I have don't have AWS support plan right now so they can't help me through this.

Looking forward to having some suggestions on this issue.

Comment: Starting from 2012, identity is implemented using cache, that is 10000 for bigint. This means you can have gaps <= 10000 and this is by design. Do you have a gap of 89568474589 or I misunderstood you?

Comment: @sepupic Did you mean identity with 'gaps'? I have set it to 1 but it is increasing to a random number like now it is 898622221. The common thing is that is always of 9 digits.

Comment: Yes I mean identity gaps. I still cannot unserstand if 898622221 is your current value or it's a difference between the current and the previuos

Comment: @sepupic 898622221 is the latest jumped identity. my default identity is 1. So my values are like this 27,28,29.  The last value increases to a random big number when identity jumped to the number like this '898622221'

Comment: I have no idea about this jump, the only thing I cn think about is that someome manually reseeded it

Comment: @sepupic Yes, I am manually reseeding it till now. But it is not a good solution for me.